# почему не отображается dataset для элементов?

Tags: javascript

Скажите пожалуйста есть ли ошибка в данном куске кока. Он должен дать каждому элементу slides dataset, но этого не происходит.

````
const slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
const container = document.querySelector(".slider__container");
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slider__item");
const sliderButton = document.querySelectorAll("");



function init() {
    for(let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++){
         const slide = slides[i];

        slide.dataset.order = i;
    }
}
init();```
````

Comment: Проверяйте, что у вас лежит в **slides** и есть ли **slide.dataset** и как там хранятся данные. Для проверки, воспользуйтесь `console.log()`

Comment: Уберите эту строку `const sliderButton = document.querySelectorAll("");`, если вы передаёте в `querySelectorAll` пустую строку, то он выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Спасибо большое)

Comment: @KanyeEast не за что :) старайтесь избегать неиспользованных строк.